# Footnotes in Q and A?

Tags: feature-request, markdown

I think I've seen someone put footnotes in both questions and answers? Is this a feature I just can't find, a feature for only moderators or not a feature at all? Would it be an idea to have this feature if it's not already one?

Answer (score 2):

The feature is available to all users.

You create a footnote by typing the following characters: `<sup>1</sup>`

It will look like this: <sup>1</sup>. Then you can change the number in the note as you like.

Also you can pretend to edit a post e.g. [click here](https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/posts/1844/edit) to see (and learn from) the [markdown](https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help) which was used to format that post.

Answer (score 0):

> Would it be an idea to have this feature if it's not already one?

Beware that there are [20,000 feature requests](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/feature-request) on meta.stackexchange.com.

It's not that they never implement new features, but generally I hope to learn to make do with whatever the existing features are.

[Markdown footnotes?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5017/139866) (which I found using [this search](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bfeature-request%5D+footnote)) is tagged 'status-declined'.